# Adding button events!

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I add buttons dynamically.. e.g. Button newButton=new Button();
Now i want each button to be triggered. So i wrote them the following events:

```
    public void response_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void quote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

  Button quote = new Button();
    Button reply = new Button();
    Button edit = new Button();

    quote.ID = "quote";
    reply.ID = "reply";
    edit.ID = "edit";
```

How do i trigger them, as soon as the user clicks on the button..will my functions above be triggered?  do i need to do the following:

this.Clicked+=quote;
this.Clicked+=reply;
this.Clicked+=edit;

if i do need to do that..where do i put those lines of code?

i use visual studio 1010. asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do  like..

```
quote.Click += new EventHandler(quote_Click);
reply.Click += new EventHandler(response_Click);
edit.Click += new EventHandler(edit_Click);
```

Comment: Or simply quote.Click += quote_Click, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to register the event of the button and associate it with particular method.

for example.

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```